# HTML background color leakage

Tags: html, css, viewport

Just to understand the concept of viewport and its relation with HTML and BODY tags.
I have setup following code and I don't get the point that why background color of HTML tag is leaking IF it has to be on entire screen that is VIEWPORT then why border is not on entire screen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html style="background: lightblue; border: 10px solid orange;">
<head>
</head>
<body style="margin-top:200px; background-color: black; color:white; border: 1px solid red;">

<p style="margin-top:0;">Hello World!!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

*EDIT*

Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/wYYBP/

And here is code using standard CSS http://jsfiddle.net/wYYBP/1/

Its passed from w3 validator http://jsfiddle.net/wYYBP/2/

Comment: For anybody to be able to answer, you will need to add a screenshot or link to an example.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly is your problem but I can tell you for sure that styling in the HTML tag is wrong. Place between `<html>` and `</html>` this code: `<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` and place all your styles in the style.css file. This is the best practice.

Comment: html tag doesn't have style attribute http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_html.asp

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I have added link now.

Comment: its not color leakage its working out of standard's, what you exactly want to do?

Comment: @Jack whatever to call it but I want to understand that at last why its displaying border from html tag styling and the background color set to same tag. (which many call are not standard one--and I agree)    Or is it a bug? If HTML styling is out of standard call then it shouldn't work altogether and its border should also not be displayed. I am confused..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me tell you what is HTML

Html is HyperText Markup Language (HTML) is the **main markup language for web pages**. HTML elements are the basic building-blocks of webpages.

> `The text between <html> and </html> describes the web page, and the
>   text between <body> and </body> is the visible page content.` [what
>   wikipedia says about Html](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML)
>
> so i would say between (html) & (/html) content(such as body, div,
>   tables) can be styled with the help of css..

and for your confusions I would suggest you to read this links first :

1. [A tale of two viewports](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html)
2. [Adding style to HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html#h-14.2)

hope this will help

Comment: It means styling HTML tag is wrong in itself. Okay I get this point BUT then display of border which is stylized in HTML tag is a bug?

Comment: who need a border around html?? if you want border around your body you can apply this on body not on html..

Comment: I understand the fact that HTML is a wrapper and displayable content should be inside BODY tag. But then displaying of border and even displaying of lightblue color leaving the fact that its out of standard is a bug because it should not have been displayed altogether.                                                      html{
    background: lightblue;
    border: 10px solid orange;
}

Comment: You should write all this to W3C they would have a perfect answer for this i guess :) though i appreciate your curiosity

Answer (score 3):

It is very uncommon to apply CSS styles to the HTML element. Remove the styles from there and everything should be fine.

Comment: I wouldn't say it is uncommon to style the HTML element at all, it's just that the inline attribute `style` isn't valid on the tag itself. However, `border` on `html` - *that* is uncommon.

Comment: You can not apply styles on html tag its complete waste what content we see is come in body not in html, html behave as a medium to the browser, its says renderthose things only which come after/between me(html)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is invalid. The html tag does not have a style attribute. You can check whether your code is valid or not at http://validator.w3.org/.